# if statement occurs, load certain page

Tags: if-statement

I am trying to create a simple "filter tool" for selecting an electric motors. Like in http://valiadis.gr. But more simple with only two drop-down filters.

What I want to improve is when both of drop-downs are selected to open the motor page directly, instead of list with only one motor.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ssTP.png "My dropdowns"

```
if($_GET["Power"]!="*" and $_GET["Poles"]!="*") $query = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE 2` WHERE Power=".$_GET["Power"]." AND Poles=".$_GET["Poles"]."";
elseif($_GET["Poles"]!="*") $query.= "SELECT * FROM `TABLE 2` WHERE Poles=".$_GET["Poles"]."";
elseif($_GET["Power"]!="*") $query.= "SELECT * FROM `TABLE 2` WHERE Power=".$_GET["Power"]."";
else $query= "SELECT * FROM `TABLE 2` ";
```

The question is what is the "command" to load a certain page (URL) directly when Case 1 happens (Power and Poles are different from "*")?

Or said otherwise - How to load a new page with PHP or Java>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "load a new page" with PHP by issuing a redirect in the response.  This instructs the client to request the target page of the redirect.  Something like this:

```
header('Location: otherpage.php');
```

Note that this should be the only response to the client.  If you render any output first, you'll receive an error indicating that headers have already been sent.  The call to `header()` should be the first output, and if issuing a redirect there shouldn't be any other output (since it'll be ignored by the client anyway).

So in your conditionals, you'd have something like:

```
if(firstCondition) {
    // some code
    header('Location: firstpage.php');
} else if (secondCondition) {
    // other code
    header('Location: secondpage.php');
} else {
    // some other code
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you! ASA I get enough reputation I will "Thank you"